# iphone development: cannot open active Facebook session with publish permission

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, permissions

In my app I want to post a image on my wall however I think i miss something. I did lots of research and end up with that code. Actually it sometimes working but generally when the code is running since there is no session with publish_action permission, second part of the code is working but the problem is I always get error log at the second part, so I cant proceed...Do you have any idea why I cant open active session with publish permissions?

```
   if ([[FBSession activeSession]isOpen]) {
        /*
         * if the current session has no publish permission we need to reauthorize
         */
        if ([[[FBSession activeSession]permissions]indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {

            [[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_action"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe
                                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,NSError *error){
                                                      action();
                                                  }];

        }else{
            [self publishStory];
        }
    }else{
        /*
         * open a new session with publish permission
         */
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                                           defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe
                                              allowLoginUI:YES
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                             if (!error && status == FBSessionStateOpen) {
                                                 [self publishStory];
                                             }else{
                                                 NSLog(@"error");
                                             }
                                         }];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first part of the code when you are requesting new publish permissions you have 
`[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_action"]` ....

If i am not not mistaken I think that should be `[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]`

Here is code snip from facebook docs
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/iossdk/errors/

```
// Method that requests permissions needed to make the API call.

    - (void)requestPermissionCallAPI {

        [FBSession.activeSession 
            requestNewPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                         defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone
                       completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                       if (error) {
                           // Handle new permissions request errors
                           [self handleRequestPermissionError:error];
                       } else {
                           // Make API call
                           ...
                       }
        }];
    }
```

Comment: well thanks for the first part. I corrected it but my main problem is the first part of the code is not even called the code always stucks in the second part since it means I cant open active session with publish permissions

Comment: As i understand the session is never open so it always tries to open the session with openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions and the completion hander shows an error?  Does that happen in bot simulator and on the phone?  Have you check the facebook permissions in the phone settings page. Is it possible that the app is not being permitted to access facebook in the phone settings and/or facebook website for this user?